# Dockerized Apache webserver runs successfully on localhost but fails on remote deployments

Tags: docker, nginx, localhost, reverse-proxy, remote-server

Newbie here with limited Java EE experience. We have received a dockerized apache webserver+postgres application from an external source. We do not have source code for this application When run locally on docker, this works perfectly, and the application is available on locahost:port. When the same docker containers are deployed remotely, the application is available at ip:port, but fails to load the js files (or rather replaces js file contents with index.html) for the javax.faces.resources, for example(core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=12.0.0)

We have attempted to put a reverse proxy in front, hoping to make it seem to the container on the remote machine that the requests are arising fron localhost, but to no avail.

We are  at a loss now. Any ideas why this could be happening? Also, what should be the reverse proxy conf to make it appear to the webserver that the requests are arising from local machine?
The ngnix conf used currently is as follows:

```
   server {
      listen 80;
      location / {
        proxy_pass        http://localhost:3301;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP        localhost;
      }
    }
```